# Azure Pipeline cross-project access to terraform-linked git repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

We have pipelines in Azure DevOps that have terraform tasks that reference git repositories in separate projects in the same Azure DevOps organization. That terraform code, in turn, has git links to other repositories in the org.

In order for our pipelines to work, we've had to set global git header in a task in the pipeline before the terraform task is run. We need to switch away from the global header, but have had little luck in doing so to this point. Is it even possible?

In case it's not clear, this is using an Azure Pipeline.

Comment: How did you link the other repositories in terraform code?

Comment: That configuration managed by a separate team, so I'll have to go ask questions. What sort of info would be helpful to answer your question?

Comment: This looks promising as a potential fix. Testing it shortly... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-181-update#uses-statement-for-pre-declaring-resources